# fastai confusion matrix classes not in order

Tags: python, deep-learning, confusion-matrix, fast-ai

I am using fastai to plot a confusion matrix of my fastai model. I am using this code:

```
interp = ClassificationInterpretation.from_learner(learn)
interp.plot_confusion_matrix()
```

My classes are `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]`.

The confusion matrix prints the classes out of order, as such: `[0,1,10,11,12,13,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Actually, they are in alphabetic order (meaning `1xxx` is before `2xxx` so `10` is before `2` :) ). The real question is: how to use a custom sorting function to treat as number?

Answer (score 0):

One simple alternative is to change your categories by adding leading zeroes for the classes (and not using the numbers):

- `1` => `01`
- `2` => `02`
- ...
- `10` => `10`

You could use the format `02d` like this:

`"{:02d}".format(category)` or even better (Python 3.x): `f"{category:02d}".

That way, you are sure that `02` is before `10`.